# Which cancers are routinely treated with anti-angiogenic therapy?

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer, treatment

I have been asked to discuss 2 of these cancers and how the therapy is used. I understand angiogenesis and its role in tumour progression, but need some help in explaining how the therapy is used.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You might want to consider giving more work on your future post. For example, spelling correctly the very concept you are interested in would be the least you should do! Make sure to always read at least the wikipedia page when there is one and make sure to let us know what you found, what you understand and what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant ["Angiogenesis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angiogenesis) instead of "Antiogenesis"...

From [wikipedia > angiogenesis inhibitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angiogenesis_inhibitor)

> Angiogenesis inhibitors were once thought to have potential as a "silver bullet" treatment applicable to many types of cancer, but the limitations of anti-angiogenic therapy have been shown in practice.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angiogenesis_inhibitor) Nonetheless, inhibitors are used to effectively treat cancer, macular degeneration in the eye, and other diseases that involve a proliferation of blood vessels

You should definitely have a look at this webpage form the [National Cancer Institute](https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/treatment/types/immunotherapy/angiogenesis-inhibitors-fact-sheet).

> Angiogenesis plays a critical role in the growth and spread of cancer. A blood supply is necessary for tumors to grow beyond a few millimeters in size. Tumors can cause this blood supply to form by giving off chemical signals that stimulate angiogenesis. Tumors can also stimulate nearby normal cells to produce angiogenesis signaling molecules. The resulting new blood vessels “feed” growing tumors with oxygen and nutrients, allowing the cancer cells to invade nearby tissue, to move throughout the body, and to form new colonies of cancer cells, called metastases.
>
> The U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) has approved bevacizumab [a angiogenesis inhibitor] to be used alone for glioblastoma that has not improved with other treatments and to be used in combination with other drugs to treat metastatic colorectal cancer, some non-small cell lung cancers, and metastatic renal cell cancer